# Chrome Bookmarks API -

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I'm attempting to create a simple example that would just alert the first 5 bookmark titles.

I took Google's example code and stripped out the search query to see if I could create a basic way to cycle through all Nodes. The following test code fails my alert test and I do not know why.

```
function dumpBookmarks() {
var bookmarkTreeNodes = chrome.bookmarks.getTree(
  function(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
   (dumpTreeNodes(bookmarkTreeNodes));
  });
}
function dumpTreeNodes(bookmarkNodes) {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (dumpNode(bookmarkNodes[i]));
}
}
function dumpNode(bookmarkNode) {
alert(bookmarkNode.title);
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just dump your `bookmarkTreeNodes` into the console and you will see right away what is the problem:

```
var bookmarkTreeNodes = chrome.bookmarks.getTree(
  function(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
   console.log(bookmarkTreeNodes);
  });
}
```

(to access the console go to `chrome://extensions/` and click on `background.html` link)

As you would see a returned tree contains one root element with empty title. You would need to traverse its children to get to the actual bookmarks.

Simple bookmark traversal (just goes through all nodes):

```
function traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
    for(var i=0;i<bookmarkTreeNodes.length;i++) {
        console.log(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].title, bookmarkTreeNodes[i].url ? bookmarkTreeNodes[i].url : "[Folder]");

        if(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children) {
            traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children);
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: How would I traverse the object as opposed to traversing the DOM? Not sure how to get around in there!

Comment: @Korak What is your goal? What are you trying to find there?

Comment: What I'm ultimately looking to do is generate a selection list of folders from the tree for display/selection by a user. Thought I should start by just figuring out how asynchronous functions are set up just to pull a bit of data and have been stumped by it! (grrr)

Comment: @Korak Well, tree(graph) structures are tricky to work with. I added example of how to traverse through all nodes. You just need to decide in which order you want to traverse it and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm going to work with your example and keep struggling along. Really appreciate it!